# Hard to understand Hazlitt's comments on Coleridge here.

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am reading a book about Coleridge who has been praised by William Hazlitt with below sentence.

> As Hazlitt said, "To the man had been given in high measure the seeds
>   of noble endowment, but to unfold them had been forbidden him."

While this comment is quite difficult to me. “had been forbidden” is a passive voice, and why it follows a pronoun (him)? Can anyone paraphrase it to plain English for easy comprehension?

Comment: BTW: can anyone share some insights on Hazlitt writing? I found most of time it's quite difficult to understand his words because of eccentric grammar style (sorry, it seems to me). Did him use ancient English or follow some special Victorian grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of figurative language. It's an elaborate trope, one which likens poetic ability to the blooming of a flower.

> The seeds of noble endowment

... all flowers start with a seed. The noble endowment is the poetic talent.

> had been given in high measure

... the potential for Coleridge's ability had been great

> but to unfold them had been forbidden him.

... but some force or circumstance had stood in the way of him fully blooming as a poet. (Read "forbidden him" as "forbidden **to** him.")

This assessment of Coleridge's ability paints him as poet [*manqué*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/manque), an unfulfilled poet, which is rather harsh considering the iconic status of poems like "The Rime of the Ancient Mariner" and "Kubla Khan."

Comment: Thorough and detailed explanation! Absolutely true for your last comment. Even Coleridge friends, Southey and Wordsworth, at that time, thought his poems not of much consequence.

Comment: @DaveHwang: All of the Lake poets were disparaged in their day. Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

This might be an easier version to follow:

> The seeds of noble endowment had been given in high measure to the man, but he was forbidden from unfolding them.

What exactly "seeds of noble endowment" are, or what it means to "unfold" them, I couldn't tell you for sure. I would guess that seeds of noble endowment has something to do with being born into a life of luxury, and unfolding them means being able to use it.

Comment: Thanks Erin, you did clarified my doubts. Based on the context of what I read, 'seeds of noble endowment' means Coleridge's imagination and fancy which are powerful inspirations for his ingenious works. He was 'forbidden to unfold' because of his suffering of illness during his later years.